# How to convert timespan to pm or am time?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm storing user time in UTC time and when I show it I need to convert it to am pm time.

Here is example in database I have 17:00:00 convert to 5:00 pm

Here is the code what I came up so far but it's not working

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(object.Time.ToString(), "HHmm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: Do you have a timespan or a UTC time? That doesn't fit together. And what's the `ToString` and parse again business about?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact("17:00", "HH:mm", null).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

returns 05:00 PM

DateTime.ParseExact is returning DateTime

Edited:

Include CultureInfo

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact("17:00", "HH:mm", null).ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: It depends on `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. Check: `var time = DateTime.ParseExact("17:00", "HH:mm", null).ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"));`.

Comment: I mean, that for culture `es-ES` it doesn't display `AM/PM`... :-)

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk: Might be nice to update with this extension method:         public static string ToAMPM(this TimeSpan timespan)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("17:00", "HH:mm", null);
            var timeString = dt.ToString("hh:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
            return timeString;
        }

Answer (score 9):

TimeSpan is a duration "17 hours", not a time. Maybe add this to a date (only) and use the existing datetime formatting options? (although watch for daylight savings)

i.e.

```
string s = DateTime.Today.Add(duration).ToString(specifier);
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget to specify appropriate culture, e.g.: `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

```
var time = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See also: [**Custom Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to display static html with my TimeSpan. So in my view I used,

```
DateTime.Today.Add(StartTime).ToString("%h:mm tt")
```

"StartTime" is my TimeSpan, it converts it to a DateTime and then displays it. My time now displays as "3:00 PM" instead of "15:00". The "%h" eliminates a leading zero for time that is between 1-9.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, first convert the `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime`:

```
var dtUtc = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
dtUtc.AddHours(timeSpanObject.Hours);
dtUtc.AddMinutes(timeSpanObject.Minutes);
```

Once it's a `DateTime`, you can convert it from UTC to localtime:

```
var dtLocal = dtUtc.ToLocalTime();
```

Only when you display it would you include AM/PM, like:

```
dtLocal.ToString("h:mm tt");
```

Comment: var time = Convert.ToDateTime(object.Time).ToLocalTime(); Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'. object.Time is a timespan

Comment: @Andrew Venture: Post edited.  I do wonder how you retrieve a `TimeSpan` object from a database; that's rather unusual!

Comment: @Andomar - SqlServer 2008 Express supports TimeSpan. ;)