# Display Time variable as am/pm

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have database column with data type `Time` (eg: `08:00:00.0000000`)

I am reading the value in the program and moving it to a variable declared as below

```
public string vartime{get;set;}
```

In the program while reading data, it has value.

```
((TimeSpan)(dr["dates"])).ToString()    "08:00:00"  string
```

I need to display this values as `08:00 am` in the grid. Also,the value `16:00:00.0000000` should be displayed as `04:00 pm`.

On giving `vartime=((TimeSpan)(dr["dates"])).ToString("hh:mm tt")`, it gives me an error as input is not in correct format.

Please let me know how can I format the Time variable to display with am/pm .

Comment: See this thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724040/how-to-convert-timespan-to-pm-or-am-time

Answer (score 0):

In sql server you could do this:

```
  declare @time datetime='16:00:00';
  SELECT substring(convert(varchar(20), @time, 9), 13, 5) 
        + ' ' + substring(convert(varchar(30), @time, 9), 25, 2)
```

**result**

```
 4:00 PM
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.I was trying similar to the link giving above,but I get the error as 'input string is not in correct format'.Is it because the datatype is 'Timespan' ?

Comment: @Soumya: yes, the datype should be datetime for the above function to work

Comment: So this line is giving error as datatyp is timespan?vartime=((TimeSpan)(dr["dates"])).ToString("hh:mm tt")

Answer (score 0):

you can do by adding timespan to datetime like,

```
    TimeSpan timespan = new TimeSpan(03,00,00);
    DateTime time = DateTime.Today.Add(timespan);
    string displayTime = time.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

instead of 03,00,00 you can directly pass your timespan variable