# AM/PM to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I want to achieve the converse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724040/how-to-convert-timespan-to-pm-or-am-time), that is, I want to convert a `string` with format `hh:mm tt` to a `TimeSpan` with zeroed seconds.

For example, `09:45 pm` is converted to `21:45:00`.

Comment: A `TimeSpan` does not have a format.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be to parse it as a `DateTime` using `DateTime.ParseExact`, and then use the [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) to exact the `TimeSpan`.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(text,
                                    "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan span = dateTime.TimeOfDay;
```

It's odd to see a leading 0 on a number of hours when you're *also* specifying an am/pm designator though. You might want "h" instead of "hh" in the format string, to allow "9:45 pm" instead of "09:45 pm".

(I'd also argue that it's a strange use of `TimeSpan` in the first place, but then the .NET date/time types are somewhat messed up in my view. I'd recommend using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), but I'm biased :)

Answer (score 25):

This work for Me.

```
TimeSpan ts= DateTime.Parse("8:00 PM").TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan tspan;

tspan = DateTime.ParseExact("01:45 PM", "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).TimeOfDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert meridiem time to timespan and also timespan to meridiem time with date and only time using below code snipet...

```
        TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Parse("8:00 PM").TimeOfDay;                        
        DateTime dateWithTimeSlot = DateTime.Today+ ts;              

        //for getting MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt format
        string dateWithMeridiemTimeSlot =  
            dateWithTimeSlot.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt: ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine("For getting MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt format: "+dateWithMeridiemTimeSlot);

        //for getting only hh:mm tt format
        string meridiemTimeSlot =
            dateWithTimeSlot.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine("For getting only hh:mm tt format: " + meridiemTimeSlot);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Let's enjoy!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The **only** way that worked for me is Convert.ToDateTime(str).TimeOfDay. ParseExact resulted with an error!

```
string str = "12:01 AM";
TimeSpan ts = Convert.ToDateTime(str).TimeOfDay;
```

taken from: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/200b35bf-9d35-4348-80a7-9f31ee91c64c/convert-short-time-string-to-time-span?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: But it is not the only way. `DateTime.Parse("12:01 AM").TimeOfDay` did work for me too.